# Connect to REST api using ASP.NET WEB APPLICATION

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have this code in my website which i'm trying to do a POST request to this api called schooltime https://schooltimeapp.docs.apiary.io/#introduction/requirements-for-apps-using-the-schooltime-api. Currently i'm trying to post 4 values from my textbox into the REST api but i am currently having some trouble on going about it as it is my first time using C# to connect to an API.

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.IO;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    private const string URL = "https://school-time.co/app2/index.php/api/students/";
    private string urlParameters = "StRest@123";
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public class Result
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
    }

    protected void Button_Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string name = TextBox_Name.Text;
        string pass = TextBox_Pass.Text;
        string email = TextBox_Email.Text;
        string birthdate = TextBox_Birth.Text;

        var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://school-time.co/app2/index.php/api/students/");

        var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse(); if (webResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {



        }
        else Label1.Text = "Invalid Response";
    }

}
```

Comment: It is better to let us know the error you are facing as well as the API that you have built and the routes for it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a client like RestSharp, then use Postman to generate the code in C#.

With your current setup, something like this within your `Button_Add_Click` may work (I have not tested it):

```
var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://school-time.co/app2/index.php/api/students/");

var postData = "name=hello";
    postData += "&email =world@test.com";
    //add other attributes...

var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

webRequest.Method = "POST";
webRequest.Headers.Add("ST-API-KEY", "StRest@123");
webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

using (var stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}

var response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();

var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

}
```

Comment: I tried your code by it keeps giving me a 403 error

Comment: @BestJeanist I am guessing you received a CORS related error ? If that's the case, you will have to execute the code on the backend, rather than on the client.